# Meaning of DHCP enabled: YES

Tags: dhcp

I'd like to ask for some help. I'm looking on a school project and I've a question to check my active connections on my network adapters. I found my adapters through ipconfig /all and now I'd like to ask if the field "DHCP enabled: Yes" stands for active connection on that adapter?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`DHCP enabled: Yes`

Simply means that DHCP is enable on that interface. So if there is a DHCP server on that network than it will get an IP address. If there isn't any DHCP server on that network then it won't get any.